# Google Drive Resumable Upload API Quotas

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth

We are using OAuth 2.0 based client and Drive V3 REST APIs. During resumable upload, client makes multiple upload calls (per chunk) for a file being uploaded. I would like to know if each of these calls (per chunk) are accounted against Google Drive API Quotas?

For example:

> API: drive.file.create
>
> Upload Type: resumable.
>
> File Size: 1 GB
>
> Chunk size: 10MB

In above scenario, how many API Quotas will be consumed for this operation for a given project?

Will this be considered 1 request against our quota or will it be ~100?

Answer (score 1):

If you are still looking for the solution, how about this answer? I think that in your situation, even if a file with the size of 1 GB was uploaded as a chunk of 10 MB using the resumable upload, Drive API is used only one time.

In my environment, when I uploaded a file with the size of 1 GB using a chunk of 10 MB as a sample, I confirmed that only one time Drive API was used at [the API dashboard](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard).

If this was difference from your environment, I'm sorry.